# Pandas Dataframe multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm new to Python, Pandas, Dash, etc. I'm trying to structure a dataframe so I can create some dash components for graphing that will allow the user to see and filter data.

At the top are aggregation characteristics, the first 3 are required and the remaining are sparse based on whether or not the data was aggregated for that characteristic. After the first ellipses, there are some summary characteristics for the day, and after the second ellipses is the time series data for the aggregation.  There are about 3800 pre-calculated aggregate groupings in this example.

Should I try to make the aggregate characteristics into a MultiIndex?

The runid is the identifier of the analysis run that created the output(same number for all 3818 columns), while the UID field should be unique for each column of a single run, but multiple runs will have the same UID with different RUNIDs.  The UID is the unique combination of CHAR1 thru CHAR20 for that RUNID and AGGLEVEL.  The AGGLEVEL is the analysis grouping which may have one or more columns of output.  CHAR3_CHAR6_UNADJ is the unique combinations of CHAR3 and CHAR6, so those two rows are populated while the remaining CHAR rows are null (well NaN)  My current example is just one run, but there tens of thousands of runs, although I usually focus on one at a time and probably won't deal with more than 10-20 at a a time for a subset of the data of each. Char1 thru Char20 are only populated if that column has data aggregated by that characteristic.

My dataframe example:

```
print(dft)
                           0      ...                 3818
UID                          32   ...                19980
RUNID                      1234   ...                 1234
AGGLEVEL             CHAR12_ADJ   ...    CHAR3_CHAR6_UNADJ
CHAR1                       NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR2                       NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR3                       NaN   ...                 1234
CHAR4                       NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR5                       NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR6                       NaN   ...                 ABCD
CHAR7                       NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR8                       NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR9                       NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR10                      NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR11                      NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR12                     IJKL   ...                  NaN
CHAR13                      NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR14                      NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR15                      NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR16                      NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR17                      NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR18                      NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR19                      NaN   ...                  NaN
CHAR20                      NaN   ...                  NaN
...
STARTTIME   2018-08-22 00:00:00   ...  2018-08-22 00:00:00
MAXIMUM                   2.676   ...             0.654993
MINIMUM                  0.8868   ...             0.258181
...
00:00                    1.2288   ...             0.335217
01:00                    1.2828   ...             0.337848
02:00                    1.2876   ...             0.324639
03:00                     1.194   ...             0.314569
04:00                    1.2876   ...             0.258181
05:00                    1.1256   ...             0.284699
06:00                    1.4016   ...             0.364655
07:00                     1.122   ...             0.388968
08:00                    1.0188   ...             0.452711
09:00                     1.008   ...             0.507032
10:00                    1.0272   ...             0.546807
11:00                     0.972   ...             0.605359
12:00                     1.062   ...             0.641152
13:00                    0.8868   ...             0.625082
14:00                    1.1076   ...             0.623865
15:00                    0.9528   ...             0.654993
16:00                     1.014   ...             0.645511
17:00                     2.676   ...              0.62638
18:00                    0.9888   ...             0.551629
19:00                     1.038   ...             0.518322
20:00                    1.2528   ...              0.50793
21:00                      1.08   ...             0.456993
22:00                    1.1724   ...             0.387063
23:00                    1.1736   ...             0.345045

[62 rows x 3819 columns]
```

Comment: You are unlikely to get many answers with a large number of wordy questions like this. By asking a specific question with a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you will get the best answers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll break it up

Answer (score 0):

You should try to transpose it with `dft.T`. You will have as index the number of your sample from 0 to 3818 and it'll be easier to select your columns then with `dft['STARTTIME']` for instance.
For the NaN, you should do `dft = dft.replace('NaN',np.nan)` so that Pandas will understand that it's really a NaN and not a string (don't forget to write `import numpy as np` before). You'll be able then to use `pd.isna(dft)` to check if you have NaN in your Dataframe or `dft.dropna()` to keep full completed lines.

Comment: I actually transposed it after importing it to get to the current design lol (dft vs df). I thought in order to graph it as time series I needed the data in columns. Can I graph time series across the page? Or should I just use a scatter plot with the 00:00 - 23:00 as the X axis?